# separate authentication, firestore within same database

Tags: android, database, firebase, android-studio

I have made 2 android apps sharing same firebase database.
1st app is for normal users and
2nd app is for car drivers.
how to separate authentication, firestore within same database

Comment: What do you mean by "separate authentication"?

Comment: i want to store user credentials from both apps in same database, but users credential info from one app should not be able to login from other app

Comment: Why not using [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)?

Comment: i m using firebase auth. i need to know in details how to apply it properly.